# In Java Generics are invariant?

Tags: java, generics

Compiling the below code is failing:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
       list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
}
```

like:

```
Swap.java:5: set(int,capture#282 of ?) in List<capture#282 of ?> cannot be applied to (int,Object)
           list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
```

But if I do this:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
       swapHelper(list, i, j);
}

private static <E> void swapHelper(List<E> list, int i, int j) { list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
}
```

Its working perfectly.

But I have a basic doubt here. Generics are said to be invariant, so `List<String>` is not subtype of `List<Object>`, right?

If that is the case, then how come in the above method, we are able to pass `List<?>` to `List<E>`?  How does this works?

Comment: Wildcards work differently from standard is-it-possible-to-assign checks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the answer is wildcards.

`List<?>` is not the same as `List<Object>`
while java assumes both are collections of Object, the former will match the type of any other `List<T>`,  while the latter will not match the type of any `List<T>` besides `List<Object>`.

example:

```
public void doSomething(List<Object> list);
```

This function will accept only `List<Object>` as it's parameter. However this:

```
public void doSomething(List<?> list);
```

will accept any `List<T>` as it's parameter.

This can be extremely useful when used with [generic constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). For instance if you'd like to write a function that manipulates numbers (`Integer`s, `Float`s, etc.) you could:

```
public void doSomethingToNumbers(List<? extends Number> numbers) { ... }
```

Comment: Not "extremely useful" really, more like a shorthand: `public void doSomethingToNumbers(List<? extends Number> numbers)` is the same as `<E extends Number> public void doSomething(List<E> numbers)`

Comment: Which is also extremely useful. However I believe the wildcard syntax in this instance is clearer and better conveys the intent of the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) capturing.

> In some cases, the compiler infers the type of a wildcard. For
>   example, a list may be defined as List but, when evaluating an
>   expression, the compiler infers a particular type from the code. This
>   scenario is known as wildcard capture.

Thanks to the helper method, the compiler uses inference to determine T, the capture variable, in the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

`List<?>` means "list of an unknown type". You can pass a `List<String>` for it, not because it is a subclass (it isn't), but because "unknown type" is supposed to accept whatever you throw at it.

Because type is unknown, you cannot perform operations with it, that require knowing the type of the elements (like `set` or `add` etc).

`List<E>` is a generic. It is not the same as `List<?>` even though it kinda looks similar. 
One difference is, as you noted, you can do things like `set` or `add` to it, because the type of the element is now known.

Whildcards as function parameters are not very useful (`<E> void foo(List<E> l)` is not much different from `void foo(List<?> l)`). They also bypass all the compile-time type check, thus defeating the purpose of generics, and should really be avoided.

A more common (and less harmful) use for wildcards is in the return types: `List<? extends DataIterface> getData()` means that `getData` returns a list of some objects that implement a `DataInterface`, but won't tell you their concrete type. This is often done in the API design to isolate implementation details from the interface. The convention usually is, that you can pass a list of objects, returned by the API to other API methods, and they will accept and handle them. This concept is called `existential types`.

Also, note that `getData` from the above example can return lists of different types, depending on some condition, that is outside of the caller's domain, unlike if it was declared to return `List<E>`, in which case, the caller would have to specify the expected type in some way.