# Java 8 generics compatibility

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following method declaration:

```
public <T extends Serializable,
        Method extends BotApiMethod<T>,
        Callback extends SentCallback<T>>
    void executeAsync(Method method, Callback callback)
```

When I use it in the following way:

```
executeAsync(editMessage, new SentCallback() {
```

it works fine but shows the type safety warnings.

But when I provide the generic type to the `SentCallback`, like:

```
executeAsync(editMessage, new SentCallback<Message>()
```

it show the following compilation error:

> The method executeAsync(Method, Callback) in the type AbsSender is not applicable for the arguments (EditMessageReplyMarkup, new
>   SentCallback(){})

Why I can't use it with `new SentCallback<Message>` ?

Comment: is `editMessage` of type `BotApiMethod<Message>`?

Comment: `EditMessageReplyMarkup extends BotApiMethod<Serializable>`

Comment: And does `Message extends Serializable` or `Message implements Serializable`?

Comment: `Message implements BotApiObject` and `BotApiObject extends Serializable`

Comment: Generics are invariant. Thus you may want to write `Method extends BotApiMethod<? extends T>` and `Callback extends SentCallback<? extends T>`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm unable to change the method declaration :(

Comment: In this case, the problem is not solveable in a clean way. You should write / talk to whoever wrote this code and request a change. Parameter `T` seems superfluous, the generics could be simplified to `<Method extends BotApiMethod<? extends Serializable>, Callback extends SentCallback<? extends Serialiable>>` (if `T` is required, it should be changed to my first solution).

Comment: @Turing85 The `T` parameter is not superfluous; it specifically requires that the generic method and callback use _the same_ generic type.

Comment: @chrylis ... which seems to be OPs problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let us take a look at the inferred type of `T`. Given the types of your parameters (`BotApiMethod<Serializable>` and `SentCallback<Message>`), `T` should be either inferred to `Serializable` or to `Message`. But at the same time the current implementation forces that both parameters have the exact same `T`. This is the reason the presented attempt does not work. Keep in mind that [in Java, generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839920/in-java-generics-are-invariant/27839991).

If one cannot change the given definition of `executeAsync(...)`, the problem is not solvable with the parameters provided.

If parameter `T` is essential and the design allows for different generic parameters of `Method` and `Callback`, which only need to have a common supertype `T`, the definition of `executeAsync(...)` could be changed to:

```
public <T extends Serializable,
        Method extends BotApiMethod<? extends T>,
        Callback extends SentCallback<? extends T>>
    void executeAsync(Method method, Callback callback)
```

If parameter `T` is not essential it could be dropped completely, leading to the following definition of `executeAsync(...)`:

```
public <Method extends BotApiMethod<? extends Serializable>,
        Callback extends SentCallback<? extends Serializable>>
    void executeAsync(Method method, Callback callback)
```

Comment: …and as a general advice, don’t mandate the element type to be `Serializable` (at compile-time) at all. Note that not even [`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject-java.lang.Object-) does this, as maintaining this trait throughout Java’s type system would be a nightmare. To name a few simple examples, `Collections.singleton("foo")` is perfectly serializable, but its compile-time type won’t tell. And so are `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` or `Comparator.naturalOrder()`. Etc.